# Have DB, need software for making it accessible in the web

Tags: api, web-apis

If you have a DB, what is the best way of letting people access it? And managing, limiting and charging for accessing it (for power users). I'd like a kind of API library/package/solution that doesn't have to be designed from scratch. I need to install it in my web-site, so, no 3rd party solutions which would provide me this as a service. The DB is a SQLite, but I am flexible on this, and willing to migrate to another DB. The hosting is still not running, so, I'd pick whatever is needed. I'm wondering if there are any Web API that let's users performs url-encoded call on the data. (and manage the call in the terms above).
I will be uploading the DB (25-30 GBs) and letting users, at least several hundreds (who would be using whatever programming language fits them best) to query the DB in the form (www.mysite.com/?a="aaaa"+b+"bbbb").  Think a content management system (CMS), that will be accessed programmatically, not with a web-browser, and would be offering one-liners, not blog texts and the like. It will need to manage (registered) users, if they exceed a threshold. The point is also that it should be implemented with minimal programming (as much as if I wanted to deploy a Python Plone web-portal) and accessed by people with minimal programming skils.

Comment: It would be nice to know what database engine you are using.  And, how are you hosting the web site?

Comment: @rrirower  updated the question.

Comment: SQLite support is built in to many products, so you need to be a bit more precise e.g. what language that API should be for. Furthermore, as it's *built into* most stuff (like Python or PHP already have a corresponding API included), what are your specific requirements? Why might those built-in APIs be not enough for you? Or aren't you talking about a programming API – in which case it's completely unclear what kind of "package/solution" you're after. A few more details can't hurt ;)

Comment: @Izzy: I am willing to adopt a different DB, if that makes things easier, so, it's not important to suggest a solution to this or that DB.

Comment: That's not the point, Quora. The point is to make your requirements clear. Currently it's "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad" at the same time (to quote some of the reasons given by votes to close this question). Maybe it can help you taking a look at some of our guidelines, e.g. [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: How about adminer.php or phpwebadmin?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple different ways you can go with this.  The first would involve running an apache distribution like [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) on your own server.  You would set up a MySQL database and make it accessible from remote computers.  XAMPP installs with everything you need.

The second is a little more expensive, but, provides more features and security.  There are several NAS (Network Attached Storage) (eg. [Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/)) devices that allow setting up a web server with full database support and remote access.

Comment: Mystery down vote.  Gotta love it....

Comment: Voted +1 and brought it back to 0.